# Slim framework route middleware arguments

Tags: authentication, slim

I'm writing my custom route authorization middleware for Slim.
If I well understand *"Route Middleware"* is different from *"Middleware"*.

I would like to use my custom router middleware this way:

```
$app->get('/',$acl->allow(["users","admins"]),function () use ($app) {
    ...
});
```

where

`$acl->allow` is my route middleware:

```
public function allow($auth=[]){
    return function() use($auth){
        ...
    };
}
```

In this docs http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Middleware I read this:

> What arguments are passed into each route middleware callable?
>
> Each middleware callable is invoked with one argument, the currently
>   matched \Slim\Route object.

How to use the standard param \Slim\Route object AND a custom parameter (in my example `["users","admins"]`)

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple answer to get both custom and route param in the route middleware callable:

```
public function allow($auth=[]){
    return function($route) use($auth){
        //this is my route:
        $route
    };
}
```